# Validate currency input in java JTextField/JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, validation, jbutton, jtextfield, currency

To start with there is part in my program when I want user to enter amount of money. It will contain either JTextField or JFormattedTextField and a button used to submit the amount. After clicking button amount entered will be added to total. The thing is that I don't want to allow user to enter anything that is not a double. I want the button to only works and actually add userinput to total if input is a double and is greaten than zero (or >= 0.01 - I don't know I am very inexperienced with currency).

I am very inexperienced, especially when it comes to working with currency. I was looking for codes examples here and in Java documentation, but they are too confusing for me. So please let me seek your wisdom and help me:

- Is it better to use JTextField or JFormattedTextField?
- How to check it to make sure that it is numeric, and double and greater or equal to 0.01?
- I want to keep button disabled from user perspective until he enters correct data. In code is it better to put all validation code under action listener and do validation there or have a TextField that validate it before I will read from it? I am confused:)